# When Harry was getting sorted, did the sorting hat speak out loud or in Harry's head?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

I know that Harry and The Sorting Hat had a conversation while he was being sorted, but did they talk in their heads or out loud. If out loud, did anybody hear the conversation?